# How to fix icons in ardesia in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: icons

I just installed ardesia on ubunty 15.04, and I can draw on screen but I can't see any icons in the sidebar, most notably I don't know how to exit the program. I had to stop it using top.

Does anyone knows how to fix the icons in the sidebar?
Does the ardesia has shortcut keys?
Is there any other program like ardesia which works better on Ubuntu?

Comment: For me, the panel is on the right side (15.04 and GNOME)

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  It seems that Ardesia steals the focus so that only its overlay window can be clicked.  And no, I can't seem to find any sort of keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Magically, the old version `ardesia_1.0-1_amd64.deb` works fine for me on Ubuntu 15.04(But only when extending the 2nd monitor).

Download it at： https://code.google.com/archive/p/ardesia/downloads